# Does camping in polar bear country require someone to keep guard during the night?

Tags: safety, bears, night, arctic

Some animals are big and dangerous and, when hungry, may realise that humans contain a pretty decent amount of meat. I've never hiked in such areas, but they do exist.

[image: polar bear warning]

Photo from [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Polar-Bear-Warning-Longyearbyen.jpg), CC-BY-SA 3.0

When on tour in Svalbard (and presumably in other polar bear territory as well), one is required to carry a rifle in order to protect oneself when attacked by a bear.

But what about during the night? Must someone stay awake all night to keep guard in case a polar bear comes for human meat?

Comment: "Avoid camping under the stars at all times and avoid camping in a tent whenever possible. If you have no other choice but to sleep outside of a hard-sided secure building" from http://www.bearsmart.com/becoming-bear-smart/safety-in-polar-bear-country

Comment: Surely that'd be "*if* attacked by a bear", unless bear attack is mandatory for entry ?

Comment: Not only do you contain a fair amount of meat, you may be the first meat meat they've seen in a while. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to take a shot at this one and say it **will not be enough** to ensure your safety.

Bears are very curious animals and they are not afraid to get in contact with humans.

Polar Bears have mastered their predilection area because they are on the top of the food chain.

For more information, please refer [here](http://www.bearsmart.com/becoming-bear-smart/safety-in-polar-bear-country)

*Taken from the above link:*  `"Avoid camping under the stars at all times and avoid camping in a tent whenever possible. If you have no other choice but to sleep outside of a hard-sided secure building"`

Comment: That quote trailed off in a sentence fragment which does not make sense by itself. The rest of the quote is "If you have no other choice but to sleep outside of a hard-sided secure building, **avoid tenting on beaches, islands, along coastlines and on travel routes.**"